# Need to fetch value of a key from a XML file using a script

Tags: powershell, shell, awk, sed

I have following XML code where I have to fetch RFCnumber value and assign it to a variable.
Ex: From below code , I have to fetch `1200021992` for RFCNumber Property name and assign it to a variable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Objects>
 <Object Type="System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject">
   <Property Name="d" Type="System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject">
     <Property Name="__metadata" Type="System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject">
       <Property Name="id" Type="System.String">https://example.com</Property>
       <Property Name="uri" Type="System.String">https://example.com</Property>
     <Property Name="LongDescription" Type="System.String">Testï¿½Descriptionï¿½ofï¿½Change</Property>
     <Property Name="OperationType" Type="System.String">new</Property>
     <Property Name="ChangeType" Type="System.String">ZMCR</Property>
     <Property Name="Status" Type="System.String">Success</Property>
     <Property Name="ShortDescription" Type="System.String">Testï¿½Shortï¿½Description</Property>
     <Property Name="CycleTypeId" Type="System.String">8200000083</Property>
     <Property Name="RfcNumber" Type="System.String">1200021992</Property>
```

I need some help in this.
I'm trying following code but it is not working:

```
$rfc = ($response -split "<d:RfcNumber>|</d:RfcNumber>")[X]
echo $rfc
```

Comment: You have added different languages tags, which language exactly you are looking to complete the code?

Comment: I'm using powershell in Azure DevOps.. but I can give it a try with any of the useful answer.

Comment: Ok, please do mention your expected output(edit your question) in your question to make it clear, thank you.

Comment: I just added that.. expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples please try following `awk` code.

```bash
awk -F'[><]' 
'/<Property Name="RfcNumber" Type="System\.String">/{
   print $3
}
' Input_file
```

***OR*** if you have only 1 `RefNumber` and you want to print only 1 value then better `exit` from command to save sometime in that case you can try following `awk` code a bit tweaked form of above:

```
awk -F'[><]' 
'/<Property Name="RfcNumber" Type="System\.String">/{
   print $3
   exit
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, setting `-F`(field separator) as `>` and `<` and in main block of program checking if line contains `<Property Name="RfcNumber" Type="System.String"` then print 3rd field which is required output by OP.

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using `sed` you can try following solution once.

```bash
sed -n '/<Property Name="RfcNumber" Type="System\.String"/{s/.*">//;s/<\/.*//p}' Input_file
```

***OR*** in case you have only 1 match of the value in whole file then better to quit/exit from program rather than reading whole Input_file in that case try following:

```bash
sed -n '/<Property Name="RfcNumber" Type="System\.String"/{s/.*">//;s/<\/.*//p;q}' Input_file
```

Comment: Ok Thanks let me give it a try...but for my understanding and knowledge, can you please tell me why we are using print $3 ?

Comment: @gauravsharma, Explanation of `awk` code and `sed` solution also been added in my answer, feel free to ask any query cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed`

```
$ rfc=$(sed -En '/RfcNumber/s/[^>]*>([^<]*).*/\1/p' input_file)
$ echo "$rfc"
1200021992
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the built-in xml parser in powershell? e.g.:

```
[xml] $x = gc infile.xml
$x.objects.object.property | ? name -like "rfcnumber" | select -exp "#text"
```

Output:

```
1200021992
```

Comment: I'm not getting the output using powershell task. How you got this output displayed, it is not displaying in my case.

Comment: @gauravsharma: this example assumes your xml data is in a file called `infile.xml` and structured as you show it in the OP

Answer (score 1):

As it is xml, using for exampe `xmllint` with an xpath query:

```
xmllint --xpath '//Property[@Name="RfcNumber"]/text()' file.xml
```

Output

```
1200021992
```

Or more specific

```
/Objects/Object[1]/Property[@Name="d"]/Property[@Name="__metadata"]/Property[@Name="RfcNumber"]/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat file | sed -n '$p' | cut -d'T' -f2 | cut -d'>' -f2 | cut -d'<' -f1
```